# How to get the Method Table for the pinned handle?

Tags: debugging, windbg, sos

I tried to dump the pinned handle by `!dumpvc` however I don't know the MethodTable for the pinned handle. How to get it?

```
0:000> !gcroot 0000000384b8a160
HandleTable:
    00000002008e1bf8 (pinned handle)
    -> 000000067fff3978 System.Object[]
    -> 00000003802f6800 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]
    -> 000000023e781020 System.Object[]
    -> 0000000384b8a160 System.String
```

Answer (score 0):

Dump the contents of the handle with `dq 2008e1bf8 L1`. Take the address located there and dump it with `!do`. This will give you the MT and the name of the type.

Alternatively, pass the address to `!sosex.gch`, like so: `!gch 2008e1bf8`

Comment: ,this not give the MT of the  pinned handle itself , it give the MT of the object it  pinned handle point to.

Comment: I have the following gcroot, and  many string cann't be GC collected, and we finally we found the string List pinned , however we don't know how to find the pin handle. BTW, we used the  System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache to store the string as a key.

===============================================
"
0:000> !gcroot 000000038245b130
HandleTable:
    00000002008e1bf8 (pinned handle)
    -> 000000067fff3978 System.Object[]
    -> 00000003802f6800 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]
    -> 000000023e781020 System.Object[]
    -> 000000038245b130 System.String
"

Comment: The pinned handle is simply a handle table entry, so there's no MT. Out of curiosity, what were you going to use the MT for, if it existed?